# how to enhance the image size of the screenshot captured for extent report?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, screenshot, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am capturing the screenshot of the screen at failure and extent report displays it. When I click on the captured screenshot in the extent report, it's not the full screen. Its short by approximately 1 cm on all sides.

How to enhance it to make it full screen?

Comment: right click on the image and 'open image i new window' ?

Comment: Version of ExtentReports?

Comment: @foursyth its 3.1.5

Comment: @Ricky Please share screenshots

Comment: thanks guys...this requirement is out of scope now...so working on something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the css style configuration in extent-config.xml.
Example below, changed the width of image.

```
<!-- custom styles -->
<styles>
    <![CDATA[
        .featherlight-image {   border: 1px solid #f6f7fa;   cursor: zoom-in;    width: 75px; }
    ]]>
</styles>
```

Check the css variables in your report and adjust the image how you want.

Answer (score 0):

For Extent Report v4 you can use htmlReporter

```
public ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;


@BeforeTest
public void setExtentReport() {
    String reportUrl = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test-output/ExtentReportVersion4.html";
    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportUrl);
    String css = ".r-img {width: 100%;}";
    htmlReporter.config().setCSS(css);
}
```